# Why do some Android phones procude garbage as video output?

Tags: android, android-camera

Despite the camera profile being present, some devices produce garbage output. Why is that? Can't I trust the manufacturer that a CameraProfile works which is present when queried? Or am I doing anything wrong? (I saw there are many posts which say I must check the available resolutions, but I don't see the reason why if the profile is present.)

Example:

The front facing camera on my Samsung Galaxy Note 2 (N7100) is specified with 1.9 Megapixels and should be able to record VGA 640x480 fine.

I am querying the camera profile like this:

```
        if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(1, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P)) { // 1 stands for front-facing camera
            recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(1, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P));
        }
```

So obviously the device is telling me that I can set that profile, but it still produces garbage.

Android also specifies that hasCamera() checks for the profile to be present: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile.html#hasProfile(int, int)

Comment: I heard somewhere that if you use some cyanogen modes it messes with Cameras, since Samsung uses something unqie with it's cameras and the new Finger Print scanner. So the current ROMs don't support the cameras + finger print scanner as a user would wish.
Is it possible that you use 3rd party ROM ?

Comment: No, I'm not using any 3rd party ROMs. The device is original, with Android updated to KitKat.

Comment: Are you calling setOrientationHint() ? I think that if you remove it, the video will come out ok, though rotated. Don't know how to completely solve this.

Comment: Yes, I am using setOrientationHint(). [I'll remove it later, run a test and let you know.]